# Extracting rows from a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, extract

I have this DataFrame:

[image: DataFrame]

I would like to extract the lines where a client is at the same time in the Block action and the Alow action, so I want the lines: 0, 2, 4 and 6.

The solution with using index of rows, i can't use it because i have millions of lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `groupby`, `filter`, and `nunique`:

```
indexes = df.groupby('client')['action'].filter(lambda x: x.nunique() >= 2).index
filtered = df.loc[indexes]
```

Output:

```
>>> indexes.tolist()
[0, 2, 4, 6]

>>> filtered
  action   client
0  block  client1
2  allow  client1
4  block  client8
6  allow  client8
```

Answer (score 0):

If `action` column is only contains, *block* and *allow* values, you can group your dataframe by `client` then, count the number of unique actions.

For example:

```
df.groupby("client")["action"].nunique()
```

If the extracted value is bigger than 1 than a specific client have the block and allow values at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer to your question which relies primarily on Python logic as opposed to Pandas logic.

It also includes a `timeit` performance comparison with a primarily Pandas based approach, which seems to show that the Python logic is more than 50 times faster for the chosen example with over 100,000 rows.

```py
import pandas as pd

# Sample data
n = 100000
recordData = [['allow' if i < n // 2 else 'block', 'ip="128.03.03.29"', 'source="29E9t 99 94"', 'destination="12300rtgR30"', 'client'+f'{i}'] for i in range(n)]
nDual = 20000
recordData += [['block'] + recordData[i % n][1:] for i in range(1, 7 * nDual + 1, 7)]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=recordData, columns=['action', 'adresse_ip', 'source_ip', 'destin_ip', 'client'])
print(f"Sample dataframe of length {len(df)}:")
print(df)

import timeit

def foo(df):
    # Selection
    blocks = {*list(df['client'][df['action'] == 'block'])}
    allows = {*list(df['client'][df['action'] == 'allow'])}
    duals = blocks & allows
    rowsWithDuals = df[df['client'].apply(lambda x: x in duals)]

    # Diagnostics
    print(f"Number of rows for clients with dual actions: {len(rowsWithDuals)}")

    return rowsWithDuals

print("\nPrimarily Python approach:")
t = timeit.timeit(lambda: foo(df), number = 1)
print(f"timeit: {t}")

def bar(df):
    indexes = df.groupby('client')['action'].filter(lambda x: x.nunique() >= 2).index
    filtered = df.loc[indexes]

    print(f"Number of rows for clients with dual actions: {len(filtered)}")

    return filtered

print("\nPrimarily Pandas approach:")
t = timeit.timeit(lambda: bar(df), number = 1)
print(f"timeit: {t}")
```

Outputs are:

```
Sample dataframe of length 120000:
       action         adresse_ip             source_ip                  destin_ip       client
0       allow  ip="128.03.03.29"  source="29E9t 99 94"  destination="12300rtgR30"      client0
1       allow  ip="128.03.03.29"  source="29E9t 99 94"  destination="12300rtgR30"      client1
2       allow  ip="128.03.03.29"  source="29E9t 99 94"  destination="12300rtgR30"      client2
3       allow  ip="128.03.03.29"  source="29E9t 99 94"  destination="12300rtgR30"      client3
4       allow  ip="128.03.03.29"  source="29E9t 99 94"  destination="12300rtgR30"      client4
...       ...                ...                   ...                        ...          ...
119995  block  ip="128.03.03.29"  source="29E9t 99 94"  destination="12300rtgR30"  client39966
119996  block  ip="128.03.03.29"  source="29E9t 99 94"  destination="12300rtgR30"  client39973
119997  block  ip="128.03.03.29"  source="29E9t 99 94"  destination="12300rtgR30"  client39980
119998  block  ip="128.03.03.29"  source="29E9t 99 94"  destination="12300rtgR30"  client39987
119999  block  ip="128.03.03.29"  source="29E9t 99 94"  destination="12300rtgR30"  client39994

[120000 rows x 5 columns]

Primarily Python approach:
Number of rows for clients with dual actions: 25714
timeit: 0.04522189999988768

Primarily Pandas approach:
Number of rows for clients with dual actions: 25714
timeit: 3.1578059000021312
```

This would seem to suggest that using a primarily Python (not Pandas) approach is preferable for large datasets.